Autocorrelation and Spectrum of a Gaussian Process
I think there is a mistake in my thinking below, where is the error?
If $x(t) \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and is temporally independent, then the autocorrelation function is $G(\tau) = \mathbb{E}[x(t)x(t+\tau)]=\sigma^2 \mathbb{1}(\tau = 0)$. That is, the autocorrelation is $\sigma^2$ when $\tau = 0$, otherwise it is $0$.
But by the Wiener-Khinchin theorem, the power spectral density is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation, so the power spectral density is just $0$ everywhere. This makes no sense to me because that is the same as the power density of a flat function. Where am I going wrong?

Hi: A normal RV can be thought of as white noise and the power spectral density of white noise is flat. See relevant section of this where it shows the spectrum of white noise. https://dsplog.com/2012/03/25/thermal-noise-awgn/#google_vignette

Note that you have to scroll down a bit and the section is called "Modeling White Noise".

I understand that white noise implies flat power spectral density, which implies dirac delta autocorrelation. But if I compute the autocorrelation of a Gaussian process directly, I do not get a dirac delta function, instead I get $G(0) = \mathbb{E}[x(t)x(t)] = \sigma^2$ (as above), but it should be $\infty$ since $G(\tau)$ should be the dirac delta function. Where is the inconsistency?

Hi Mashe: I'm not clear on why you think it should be infinity. It may have something to do with the notation because some books vary in terms of how they present the dirac delta. See this for a possible cause of the confusion.  I hope it helps. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83322/is-a-white-noise-always-zero-mean-and-uncorrelated
